# Windows Server 2003 32bit make use of 4Gb Ram

Tags: windows

In windows server 2003 32bit have installed 4Gb Ram and when i check in System Properties it shows only 3Gb of use and how to use remaining Please help me Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Go into your BIOS and look for a setting called 'memory remapping'. Turn it off. That should get you about 3.5GB or so of usable memory, which is about the best a 32-bit OS (without PAE support) can do.

Alternatively, make sure memory remapping is on and enable [PAE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283037) support. This requires the Enterprise or Datacenter edition of Windows Server 2003.